# Best cross platform image dimensions for full screen pictures on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, image, tablet

I'm developing a mobile app that will be available on both android and ios.

The app should display some high quality downloaded pictures in full screen.

The original photos have very varying dimensions such as

5184 x 3456,
2048 x 1365,
1920 x 1143

etc ...

I am trying to figure out the best "standard" picture dimensions (WxH) that I should use to deliver these photos on the devices so that quality is preserved (best possible look and feel for the device) but transfer size stays acceptable.

For example I believe that a 5184 x 3456 picture is overkill even for a High res tablet or ipad.

So my question really comes to what is the best "standard"/cross platform image dimensions that will fit most of the tablets out there while preserving the original high resolution feel of the picture.

I'm also thinking about a couple of scenarios :

1 -  build a server side database of all the pictures in different dimensions and depending on the requesting device, deliver the the picture with dimensions that matches best the dimensions of the screen's device.

OR

2- use one standard MAX picture size that the device will need to dynamically scale down at runtime. In which case, what is the standard MAX picture size that I should use to cover most tablets and smart phones.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with scenario 1. You don't want to have to deliver those massive pictures and resize them on the device. You'd just be wasting bandwidth, memory, and CPU to save on a bit of server-side complexity.

Comment: ok! thanks a lot. I'll just wait to see if anyone else has anything else to say before accepting  :)